# Requiring an html page but not echoing it

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I'm working with json and AJAX in order to get some HTML without refreshing the page. The AJAX call call a function that simplified is like this:

```
function postHTML($post) { // returns the HTML structure for a post starting from an array of variables
    # other stuff
    require('post.template.php'); // which is mostly HTML with just few php variables embedded
}

$data = '';
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $data .= postHTML($post);
}
```

After this I manage the json as follows:

```
echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'data' => $data));
```

Where data should be the HTML structure of each post loaded.
The problem is that when i require the 'post.template.php' file it uses require and it returns the data to Javascript as:

```
[HTML posts] {"success": true, "data": ""}
```

How can I get the HTML into a variable and then pass it to `json_encode` without actually requiring the page (that should still be executed as PHP)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**Output buffering**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), arround your require, to capture the output, preventing it from being echoed : it'll get stored in memory, and you'll be able to fetch it to a variable.

Basically, this would mean using the following kind of code :

```
ob_start();

// Output is no longer sent to the standard output,
// but stored in memory
require('post.template.php');

// Fetch the content that has been stored in memory
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

As a couple of references :

- [**`ob_start()`**](https://www.php.net/ob_start)
- [**`ob_get_clean()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

function postHTML($post) { // returns the HTML structure for a post starting from an array of variables
    ob_start();
    # other stuff
    require('post.template.php'); // which is mostly HTML with just few php variables embedded
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $output;
}

$data = '';
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $data .= postHTML($post);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all of the data-generating code in another function and call it when necessary. (Yes nested functions are allowed in PHP, but not sure this works in your case since you're using 'require')

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: Edited and added "not sure this works in your case since you're using 'require'" to the end of my post since i don't have in mind a way you could direct the output of require to an string. Yes The best way seems to be the output buffering others explained.